# ReactJS createRef for N components, all point to the final one in the list

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-ref

I have 3 components, App, Parent and Child. The App uses a method provided by Parent and registers the children into Parent. This is for the Parent to collect the Refs (create a dependency map) of the Children it encompasses.

Child has a method named Animate which will be invoked by Parent via refs created.

When I try to print the  dependencyMap I can see an array is being generated, the way I expect.

But when I try to access the child components from Parent using the dependencyMap, it always invokes the last on on the list of children.

That is to say, when I try to animate  < CustomComponent > using animateDependentChildren within Parent.js, the CustomComponent2 only gets animated, even if I pass the correctId for CustomComponent1.

```
App.js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <Parent>
        {
          (props)=>{
            return(
              <View>
                <CustomComponent1 ref={props.register('s1')} key={1}>Text</CustomComponent1>
                <CustomComponent2 ref={props.register('s2')} key={2}>Text2</CustomComponent2>
                <ListComponent id={'s1'} key={3}/>
                <ListComponent id={'s2'} key={3}/>
              </View>
            )
          }
        }
      </Parent>
    );
  }
}


Parent.js
class Parent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.dependencyMap = {}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.props.children({
         register: this.register.bind(this)
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }

  register(dependentOn){
    let dependentRef = React.createRef();

    if(!this.dependencyMap[dependentOn]){
      this.dependencyMap[dependentOn] = [];
    }
    this.dependencyMap[dependentOn].push(dependentRef);

    return dependentRef;
  }

  animateDependentChildren(listId){
    let subscribers = this.dependencyMap[listId];

    subscribers.forEach(subscriber => {
        console.log('subscriber', subscriber);
        console.log('subscriber dom', subscriber.current);
        this.refs[subscriber].animate(scrollObj); // <-This function always animates the last of the list of children (ie CustomComponent2)
    });
  }
}
```

Any idea what Im doing wrong here? Cant React.createRef be used to create multiple references and then invoke them later individually?

Comment: There's no such problem with multiple references. They are independent. Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve with a demo. The problem is likely elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As **subscriber** is the component ref, try changing this line:

```
this.refs[subscriber].animate(scrollObj);
```

...to:

```
subscriber.animate(scrollObj);
```

I hope this helps.